# Node.JS/Express store DB config for different environment in JSON

Tags: json, node.js, express

I'm running NodeJS Express app,

Currently have `dev` env, `test` env, and `prod` env.

However, the DB connection settings are in the code, **is there a secure and best practice way to store DB config and all other configs in JSON file format** by declaring them in a module (separately for each env or all in one module to be exported, maybe have a default.JSON, Dev.JSON, Prod.JSON...etc) for each environment then require them accordingly by setting the correct configuration for the correct environment in app.js.

I would like to achieve this without depending on any 3rd party package like .env or ncof.

Answer (score 0):

You can require file based on the environment.

```
const env = 'test';  // This value can be taken from config or .env
const configs = require(`../path/${env}`);
console.log('DB Config', configs.DB_PATH);
```

Depending on your environment you can load the file. And value for environment can be retrieved from .env or any other config.

Comment: With this, you force the environment, directly in your code. Not really dynamic.

Comment: Not actually, your ```env``` value can be configured. And depending on that you can change that value.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I think env value can be retrieved from Node_ENV and set by set.app in the express, correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve env value from Node_ENV. And if you don't require that value in future I don't think there is need to store it using set.app.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the main NodeJs hosting providers uses a simple environment variable. You can use this :

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

For defining it by yourself, for exemple 'development' on your local, you can do :

```
NODE_ENV=developpment node yourapp.js
```

With this, I suggest you to use a config tool, like nconf (there are some good competitors). You can do like this for example :

```
nconf
    .argv() // Takes arguments from CLI
    .file('./env.' + process.env.NODE_ENV + '.json') // takes from specific env file
    .file('package', './package.json'); // takes from package.json
```

Here priority is from the most important to the least :
1) argv
2) specific environment file
3) package.json